# Extract value from json using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having the below json

```
{
    "clusterName": "IBDCluster", 
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default", 
        "primary": "X92SL224XXX2XX:3306", 
        "ssl": "REQUIRED", 
        "status": "OK_NO_TOLERANCE", 
        "statusText": "Cluster is NOT tolerant to any failures. 1 member is not active.", 
        "topology": {
            "X92SL224XXX1XX:3306": {
                "address": "X92SL224XXXXXXX:3306", 
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "ONLINE", 
                "version": "5.7.36"
            }, 
            "X92SL224XXX2XX:3306": {
                "address": "X92SL224XXX2XX:3306", 
                "memberRole": "PRIMARY", 
                "mode": "R/W", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "ONLINE", 
                "version": "5.7.36"
            }, 
            "X92SL224XXXX3XX:3306": {
                "address": "X92SL224XXX3XX:3306", 
                "instanceErrors": [
                    "ERROR: group_replication has stopped with an error."
                ], 
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY", 
                "memberState": "ERROR", 
                "mode": "R/O", 
                "readReplicas": {}, 
                "role": "HA", 
                "status": "(MISSING)", 
                "version": "5.7.36"
            }
        }, 
        "topologyMode": "Single-Primary"
    }, 
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "X92SL224XXXXXXX:3306"
}
```

I need to extract value like **memberRole, status** from the **topology** section.

when I go to the topology part

```
$ClusterDetails = $ClusterStatus.defaultReplicaSet.topology
```

the **$ClusterDetails** have value like (data visible only for 2 servers but all 3 servers are present)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ClusterDetails

X92SL224XXXX1XX:3306                                                                                                   X92SL224XXXX2XX:3306                              
--------------------                                                                                                   --------------------                              
@{address=X92SL224XXXX1XX:3306; memberRole=SECONDARY; mode=R/O; readReplicas=; role=HA; status=ONLINE; version=5.7.36} @{address=X92SL224XXXX2XX:3306; memberRole=PRIM...
```

from shell I am able to see the individual output if i select like

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ClusterDetails.'X92SL224XXXX1XX:3306'


address      : X92SL224XXXX1XX:3306
memberRole   : PRIMARY
mode         : R/W
readReplicas : 
role         : HA
status       : ONLINE
version      : 5.7.36
```

I need help to fetch the data from **$ClusterDetails** for individual servers like above but not getting how to get that dot part via script. please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Something like `$ClusterDetails.'X92SL224XXXX1XX:3306'.memberRole` should work from script as well. Please clarify what exactly does not work. An [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a long statement but this should work:

```bash
$json.defaultReplicaSet.topology.PSObject.Properties.Value | Select-Object memberRole, status

# Results in:

memberRole status
---------- ------
SECONDARY  ONLINE
PRIMARY    ONLINE
SECONDARY  (MISSING)
```

You can access the **Values** of each **Property** of the **Object** in `$json.defaultReplicaSet.topology` accessing the [PSObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject) Properties.

It's worth noting that `.PSObject.Properties.Value` works to enumerate all **Property Values** at once due to [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2).

The same can be accomplished using a loop, for example:

```
foreach($property in $json.defaultReplicaSet.topology.PSObject.Properties) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ThisProperty = $property.Name
        memberRole   = $property.Value.memberRole
        status       = $property.Value.status
    }
}
```